# Straight leg sliding lunge

Tags: bodyweight-exercises, exercise-technique, legs

I found on instagram following exercise. Some kind of straight leg sliding lunge performed by a track and field athlete.

How is this exercise called and what is the purpose and focus of this exercise.

[image]

[Source](https://www.instagram.com/reel/C0wltL_CJDA)